# Executing a powershell script with arguments in VB

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am looking to execute a ps1 script with parameter through VB .net but unable to do so. we don't want to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

I would like to know if there is a simple method to execute a ps1 script with added parameter or argument.

Right now what we are using is bascially the same as `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` our code is
`C_A_H_WindowsCoreCore.U_G_C_U_Process.G_S_ExecuteExecutable("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\dummy\folder\name\RandomFile.ps1", "-Argument value")`

Comment: Why don't you like to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`? Suggesting an alternative depends on the reason why it is to be avoided.

Comment: Ditto to what vonPryz said. As that call is the accepted best/documented best practice, regardless of the language used. YOu are not showing what errors, if any your are having, which just leaves us her to assume.   --- As for your query, just pass it in the proper scope and properly quoted. Your code looks like your attempt at creating your own PowerShell host. I say this because there are no public docs on that string.